# Will extra teeth on a chainring work?

Tags: chainring

The current chainring im using has 32 teeth but I need to buy a new one. The reason is because the chainring I'm using is actually from a 3x set so the teeth does not have narrow wide teeth which is why my chain keeps falling off. So I searched online, I found a 34 tooth chainring and I want to know if 2 extra teeth will affect anything on my bike. I haven't bought it yet, I want to know if it is okay to buy it.

Comment: It's going to shift gearing range towards higher ratio. You'll loose lower gear ration and gain high gear ratio.

Comment: so i can use it?

Comment: Sure, but make sure the chain length is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two extra teeth will increase your gear ratios by 6% (34/32 = 1.06). What it will *not* do is help retain you chain any better.

Did you shorten the chain when you removed the inner and outer rings? (Assuming that's what you did.) If you didn't that may be why you are dropping the chain - it's too slack. BTW, you can re-install the front derailleur to act as a chain guide.

If you did shorten the chain you may have to replace it to accommodate the new larger chainring.

Comment: From the OP, it sounds like the new ring is a narrow-wide design, so it will help with retention. It's also hard to imagine that the chain is sized such that engaging 1 more tooth will push the derailleur beyond its absolute limits

Comment: is there a big difference? 6% doent sound like much